# How can I infer generic parameter in extension?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a very simple **CustomView** which it takes a View and modify it! Like this code:

```
struct CustomView<ViewType: View>: View {
    
    let content: () -> ViewType
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return content()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
        
    }
    
}
```

So far so good!

Now I want make a **CustomModifier** out of it, like this:

```
extension View {

    func customModifier<ViewModifierType: View>(viewModifier: () -> ViewModifierType) -> some View {

        // how can I import self from here?
        
        return viewModifier()
        
    }

}
```

use case:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        

        Text("Hello, World!")
            .customModifier(viewModifier: { CustomView(content: { Text("Hello, World!") } ) }) // <<: Here is the issue!

        // How can I satisfy CustomView with self in extension? that could help to cut Text("Hello, World!") to feeding as content for CustomView?
        
    }
    
}
```

So if see the codes, all I am trying to do is cut off `Text("Hello, World!")` with using self from extension and trying to have this form of coding:

```
.customModifier(viewModifier: { CustomView() })
```

PS: I know that for having form of `CustomView()` I have to respect the generic parameter `CustomView` with word of `where` but I do not know how can I put these all puzzle together!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then try this

```
extension View {
    func customModifier<ViewModifierType: View>(viewModifier: (Self) -> ViewModifierType) -> some View {
        return viewModifier(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried myself before asking my question! if I use `(Self) -> ViewModifierType` i have to use `view in` which I do not want it! I want my use case be like this: `.customModifier(viewModifier: { CustomView() })` that means I pass the needed View of CustomView with `self`, the use case of your Answer it does not look like what I want. I have `() -> ViewType` not `(Self) -> ViewType`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your goal but if you just want to add a red foreground to a view you need to implement a view modifier:

```
struct RedForeground: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

---

And then just call it using the modifier method:

```
Text("Text")
    .modifier(RedForeground())
```

If you want to simplify it further you can extend `View` and add make it a computed property:

```
extension View {
    var redForeground: some View { modifier(RedForeground()) }
}
```

---

usage:

```
Text("Text")
    .redForeground
```

Comment: That one I know Leo! look my question please, I want make a CustomModifier! which would try work like this:  `.customModifier(viewModifier: { CustomView() })` you see the similarity there with your code: `.modifier(RedForeground())` I want to make my `.customModifier()` act like `.modifier()`

Comment: You need to return `ModifiedContent<Self, T>`

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it, but I done nothing! I was hoping that I could make it without messing with `ModifiedContent<Self, T>`

Comment: @swiftPunk so you want to pass a View instead of a ViewModifier to your method? I am not sure if that's possible otherwise what would be the purpose of a ViewModifier type?

Comment: Leo the purpose of this question is passing generic parameter to `CustomView`. It can be done in extension. Because we have `self` there, and if I pass self from extension it would be this `(Self) -> ViewType ` which would looks like this: `.customModifier(viewModifier: { view in CustomView(content: { view } ) } )` see the other answer, my issue is that generic parameter is passing in body! I want this happen in extension, my Goal is something like this: `.customModifier(viewModifier: { CustomView() })`

Comment: **protocol ViewModifier - Adopt the ViewModifier protocol when you want to create a reusable modifier that you can apply to any view.** In other words IMO forget about trying to modifiy a view passing another View.

Comment: I think we are going in wrong way, the question is not about `protocol ViewModifier` or even about `.modifier()`. The codes that you see I put in my question are example, the goal is satisfying the generic parameter of a Struct without explicitly coding an `init()` and using `where`. For example I want to have `CustomView()` from `CustomView(content: <#T##() -> _#>)` without making `init()` for it.

Comment: If you read my question, the nature of question is inferring generic parameter in extension with self. That is the all idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just init `CustomView` without a view, but you can pass `CustomView` initializer as function to `customModifier`, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .customModifier(viewModifier: CustomView.init)
    }
}

struct CustomView<ViewType: View>: View {
    
    let content: ViewType
    
    var body: some View {
        return content
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
    
}

extension View {
    func customModifier<ViewModifierType: View>(viewModifier: (Self) -> ViewModifierType) -> some View {
        return viewModifier(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language `CustomView.init` would suffice